# Don't use JSON schema when edition YAML file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, yaml, schema

By default my Visual Studio Code uses a JSON schema definition when editing YAMl files. How to turn this off and simply use YAML syntax highlighting without specific JSON schema? In the schema selector there is not "No schema".

[image]

- Visual Studio code 1.66.0

Comment: Yaml support is apparently part of the Redhat plugin rather than a built-in feature: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143621

Comment: Here is some documentation on it: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-yaml#associating-a-schema-to-a-glob-pattern-via-yamlschemas.  I couldn't get this to work for me though.

Answer (score 9):

When you select the schema, there should be new file generated `.vscode/settings.json`

You can remove the related settings in the file under `yaml.schemas`.

Comment: This parameter is not set in my settings.json

Answer (score 8):

You can also define what schema to use with a comment at the top of the yaml file.

If you don't have a schema, you can use the yamllint schema, which doesn't expect any special content, but just warns you about possible general problems:

```yaml
# yaml-language-server: $schema=https://json.schemastore.org/yamllint.json

your:
  normal: yaml goes here
```

Comment: Ah, the declarative approach.  Love it.

Comment: This did the trick nicely. Gitlab built include/inputs into a header section before the --- and I believe it is messing with their native validation. I am no longer seeing red everywhere now. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

you can disable auto yaml schema in settings, search for `Yaml > Schema Store: Url` and disable it

Answer (score 3):

Like I mentioned in the comments, yaml support isn't currently a part of VS Code, but is part of an extension (like the [Redhat Plugin](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-yaml#associating-a-schema-to-a-glob-pattern-via-yamlschemas)).  The config in this plugin follows a similar pattern for the built in json schema settings though.

The config is defined like this:

```
{
    ...
    "yaml.schemas": {
        "schema-filename.json": FILENAME or PATTERN or LIST OF FILENAMEs/PATTERNS
    }
    ...
}
```

I don't know if this helped but if you create a dummy schema file like this `{"type": "object"}`.  You can reference that in the settings.

Also, I found that in addition to the user settings, the plugin **was writing to the workspace settings**.  Fixing things in both places seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can associate the file whose JSON schema you want to disable with a YAML lint schema.

VSCode >> (gear button: bottom left) >> Settings >> yaml.schemas (type in) >> User (tab) >> Edit in settings.json

```
{
    "yaml.schemas": {
        "https://json.schemastore.org/yamllint.json": "file:///c%3A/Users/____.yml"
```